# Draw line and text starting from the centre of sphere objects [ThreeJS]

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am working on a solar system model using ThreeJS. When I click on a planet name, the camera focuses on that planet; I want to draw a (2D) line starting from the center of the planet connecting the planet itself to some text (showing some infos like mass, speed, etc...)

How can I achieve this?
[image: example]

Answer (score 1):

Normally, the center of a sphere mesh can be simply obtain by using its [position](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/Object3D.position) property. The position of the label can be derived (e.g. by using the sphere's AABB) or by pre-defining it. It both cases, you end up with at least two points than you can use to setup your line like so:

```js
const points = [ spherePosition, labelPosition ]; // instances of Vector3

const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints( points );
const material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff0000 } );

const line = new THREE.Line( geometry, material );
scene.add( line );
```